# interpreting R code function

Tags: r

I would like to perform pathway enrichment analyses.
I have 21 list of significant genes, and mutiple types of pathways I would like to check (ie. check for enrichment in KEGG pathways, GOterms, complexes etc.).

I found this example of code, on an old BioC post.  However, I am having trouble adapting it for myself.

Firstly,
1- what does this mean?  I don't know this multiple colon syntax.

```
hyperg <- Category:::.doHyperGInternal
```

2 - I don't understand how this line works.  hyperg.test is a function that needs 3 variables passed to it, correct?  Is this line somehow passing "genes.by.pathways, significant.genes, and all.geneIDs to thr hyperg.test?

```
pVals.by.pathway<-t(sapply(genes.by.pathway, hyperg.test, significant.genes, all.geneIDs))
```

Code that I would like to adapt

```
library(KEGGREST)
library(org.Hs.eg.db)

     # created named list, length 449, eg:
     # path:hsa00010: "Glycolysis / Gluconeogenesis"

pathways <- keggList("pathway", "hsa")

     # make them into KEGG-style human pathway identifiers
human.pathways <- sub("path:", "", names(pathways))

   # for demonstration, just use the first ten pathways

demo.pathway.ids <- head(human.pathways, 10)
demo.pathways <- setNames(keggGet(demo.pathway.ids), demo.pathway.ids)

genes.by.pathway <- lapply(demo.pathways, function(demo.pathway) {
     demo.pathway$GENE[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
      })

all.geneIDs <- keys(org.Hs.eg.db)

   # chose one of these for demonstration.  the first (a whole genome random
   # set of 100 genes)  has very little enrichment, the second, a random set
   # from the pathways themselves,  has very good enrichment in some pathways

set.seed(123)
significant.genes <- sample(all.geneIDs, size=100)
#significant.genes <- sample(unique(unlist(genes.by.pathway)), size=10)

   # the hypergeometric distribution is traditionally explained in terms of
   # drawing a sample of balls from an urn containing black and white balls.
   # to keep the arguments straight (in my mind at least), I use these terms
   # here also

hyperg <- Category:::.doHyperGInternal
hyperg.test <-
    function(pathway.genes, significant.genes, all.genes, over=TRUE)
{
    white.balls.drawn <- length(intersect(significant.genes, pathway.genes))
    white.balls.in.urn <- length(pathway.genes)
    total.balls.in.urn <- length(all.genes)
    black.balls.in.urn <- total.balls.in.urn - white.balls.in.urn
    balls.pulled.from.urn <- length(significant.genes)
    hyperg(white.balls.in.urn, black.balls.in.urn,
           balls.pulled.from.urn, white.balls.drawn, over)
}

pVals.by.pathway <-
    t(sapply(genes.by.pathway, hyperg.test, significant.genes, all.geneIDs))

print(pVals.by.pathway)
```

Comment: Is the code not behaving as you expect or are you just trying to just understand it better?  It is unclear if you have a problem or simply want information.

Comment: @cdeterman - Both, I don't really understand it, especially the last line, which makes it hard to alter it, and I"m getting this error > pVals.by.pathway <-
+ t(sapply(genes.by.pathway, hyperg.test, significant.genes, all.geneIDs))
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "hyperg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting your error is because it appears you don't have the `Category` package installed from bioconductor.  I suspect this because of the triple colon operator `:::`.  This operator is very similar to the double colon operator `::`.  Whereas with `::` you can access exported objects from a package without loading it, the `:::` allows access to non-exported objects (in this case the `hyperg` function from `Category`).  If you install the `Category` package the code runs without error.

With regard to the `sapply` statement:

```
pVals.by.pathway<-t(sapply(genes.by.pathway, hyperg.test, significant.genes, all.geneIDs))
```

You can break this down into the separate parts to understand it.  Firstly, the `sapply` is iterating over the elements of `gene.by.pathway` and passing them to the first argument of `hyperg.test`.  The following arguments are the two addition parameters.  It is a little unclear and I personally recommend that people explicitly identify the parameters to avoid unexpected surprises and avoids the need for the exact same order.  This is a little repetitive in this case but a good way to avoid a silly bug (e.g. putting `significant.genes` after `all.geneIds`)

Rewritten:

```
pVals.by.pathway <-
  t(sapply(genes.by.pathway, hyperg.test, significant.genes=significant.genes, all.genes=all.geneIDs))
```

Once this loop completes, the `sapply` function simplifies the output in to a matrix.  However, the output is much more user-friendly by taking the transpose `t`.

Generally speaking, when trying to understand complex `apply` statements I find it best to break them apart in to smaller parts and see what the objects themselves look like.

Comment: thank you, this helps, I didn't know you could pass parameters to a function this way